# south (django app) doesn't alter table even though migration is saved in db

Tags: django, fabric, django-south

Ok so basically when I deploy using Fabric, the south migrate command is being run on the remote machine and fabric outputs that each migration (i.e. 10 of them) were completed. However checking (via explain) the table that the 10th migration should alter reveals that the table was not altered (yes, the 10th migration file exists). So basically the 9th migration was applied fine, but the 10th was not, even though there is a migration entry for migration #10 in the south migration history table.

Even more strangely, when I do the migration manually on the remote server, it runs fine (assuming there is no entry for migration 10 in the south migration history table) and the table is altered appropriately when checked w/ explain.

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Have you upped the verbosity on the south migrations? Also you can use --show=debug to get more info out of the fab runs.